# modify lists removing elements without making a mess

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I'm trying to resolve now a task that sounds like that:

> ''write a function modi(la, lb) that takes in input 2 lists la and lb that have the same number of elements inside. The function should **modify** lists la and lb camparing elements with the same indexes in two lists and deleting a bigger one, if elements are equal function delete both of them. ''

For example:

- la = ['bear', 'tiger', 'wolf', 'whale', 'elephant']
- lb = ['swan', 'cat', 'dog', 'duck', 'rabbit']

So the functin should return:
['bear','elephant']
['cat','dog','duck']

I have wrote the next code but it doesn't modify lists but create new ones and add there elements. Some ideas how can i do that?

```
def confront(s1, s2):   

    if s1 < s2:   # condition that tells which element to choose later
        return 0
    elif s2 < s1:
        return 1
    else:
        return 2


def modi(la,lb):

    latemp = []

    lbtemp = []

    i = 0

    while i < len(la):


        q = confront(la[i], lb[i])
        if q == 0:
            latemp.append(la[i])

        elif q == 1:
            lbtemp.append(lb[i])


        i +=1  
    la = latemp
    lb = lbtemp
    return la, lb
```

I have tried remove() but it have created a big mess

Comment: Shouldn't the answer be `[]` and `['cat','dog','duck','rabbit']`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This will solve your problem. I think it's easier than all other solutions.

```
def modi(la, lb):
    new_la = []
    new_lb = []
    for a, b in zip(la, lb):
        if a == b:
            continue
        if a > b:
            new_lb.append(b)
        if a < b:
            new_la.append(a)
    return new_la, new_lb
```

If You, however, want to change EXISTING lists, You could do this:

```
def modi(la, lb):
    del_la = []
    del_lb = []
    for i, (a, b) in enumerate(zip(la, lb)):
        if a == b:
            del_la.append(i)
            del_lb.append(i)
        if a > b:
            del_la.append(i)
        if a < b:
            del_lb.append(i)
    for x in del_la[-1::-1]:
        del la[x]
    for x in del_lb[-1::-1]:
        del lb[x]
    return la, lb
```

Comment: The `modi(la,lb)` function should **modify** lists `la` and `lb`, but your solution does not.

Comment: That's the problem. i do in the same exact way creating in the beginning empty lists and appending elements in them so in the end i return new lists.

Comment: I've added another solution (based on first one) to change existing list.

Comment: sorry, i havn't seen your second code! now i see and i would like to ask what does 'enumerate(zip(la, lb))' means

Comment: `zip` is used to go through both lists at the same time until end of shorter list is reached. `enumerate` just enumerates passes in `for` loop (which is great to use as index later). If You like this answer, please accept it.

Comment: I think @m.antkowicz's solution is better than this one.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `del` to delete list item. Also you should iterate from end to the beginning because if you will go from the beginning and delete let say `1st` element the element that was on the `3rd` place will be now on the `2nd`

It should look like

```
#you need to handle what if len of lists is 0, if lens are not the same and so on...
def compare_and_delete(list1, list2):
    i = len(list1) -1
    while i >= 0:
        if list1[i] > list2[i]:
            del list1[i]
        elif list2[i] > list1[i]:
            del list2[i]
        else:
            del list1[i]
            del list2[i]

        i-=1

        return list1, list2

l1, l2 = compare_and_delete(['bear', 'tiger', 'wolf', 'whale', 'elephant'], ['swan', 'cat', 'dog', 'duck', 'rabbit'])
```

Comment: Thank you! Ihave a question of ignorant person who study programming just 3 weeks: What is returning this function? because when i an running it it returns nothing.....

Comment: Yup - you need to add return statement check out my edit

Answer (score 0):

Generally, when you're mutating a list while iterating over it. It's good practice to iterate over a copy instead. Below is an example of what you would do to mutate one list.

```
list = []
list_copy = list[:]
for i in list_copy:
    list.remove(i)
return list
```

This allows you to maintain the correct index per iteration.

Below is my attempt to explain what I meant and using a for loop to get your expected result. Hope it helps.

```
def confront(s1, s2):

if s1 < s2:   # condition that tells which element to choose later
    return 0
elif s2 < s1:
    return 1
else:
    return 2


def modi(la,lb):
    la_copy = la[:]
    lb_copy = lb[:]

    for i in range(len(la_copy)):
        q = confront(la_copy[i], lb_copy[i])
        if q == 0:
            lb.remove(lb_copy[i])
        elif q == 1:
            la.remove(la_copy[i])

    return la, lb


la = ['bear', 'tiger', 'wolf', 'whale', 'elephant']
lb = ['swan', 'cat', 'dog', 'duck', 'rabbit']
```

Calling it via a print() will get the returned two lists.

Note: this returns a tuple. IF you'd like seperate lists call it via the following.

```
list1, list2 = modi(la,lb)
print(list1)
print(list2)
['bear', 'elephant']
['cat', 'dog', 'duck']
```

Answer (score 0):

In your own code `la = latemp` and `lb = lbtemp` create *references* to the two new lists that are local to the function, they have no bearing on the lists that you pass in to the function. According to your specs, you should be mutating the lists passed in not reassigning or creating new lists.

Since you are doing an elementwise comparison, you could use *zip* and remove from each list according to your specs:

```
def modi(la, lb):
    for i, j in zip(la, lb):
        # both the same
        if i == j:
            la.remove(i) 
            lb.remove(i)
        # element from la is bigger
        elif i > j:
            la.remove(i)
        # else element from lb must be bigger
        else:
            lb.remove(j)


la = ['bear', 'tiger', 'wolf', 'whale', 'elephant']
lb = ['swan', 'cat', 'dog', 'duck', 'rabbit']

modi(la, lb) # will modify the lists passed in.

print(la, lb)
```

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, you need to keep track of how many times you've deleted from each list, and offset your indexing by that amount. Here's a basic approach:

```
>>> a
['bear', 'tiger', 'wolf', 'whale', 'elephant']
>>> b
['swan', 'cat', 'dog', 'duck', 'rabbit']
>>> i = j = 0
>>> for k, (str1,str2) in enumerate(zip(a,b)):
...     if len(str1) == len(str2):
...         del a[k-i], b[k-j]
...         i += 1
...         j += 1
...     elif len(str1) > len(str2):
...         del a[k-i]
...         i += 1
...     else:
...         del b[k-j]
...         j += 1
... 
>>> a
[]
>>> b
['cat', 'dog', 'duck', 'rabbit']
>>>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can take advantage of the fact that assigning to a slice modifies the list:

```
la[:] = latemp
lb[:] = lbtemp
```